# Why aren't created Opportunity Product

Tags: apex, javascript, javascript-controller

### ElectronicCigaretteOpportunityComponentController.js

```
createOpportunity:function(component, event, helper) {
        let action = component.get("c.createOpportunityMethod");
        let store =component.get("v.selectedStore");
        console.log(store);
        // store.sobjectType='Store__c';
        console.log("/////////ElectronicCigaretteOpportunityComponent////////");
        let leadId = component.get("v.leadId");
        let contactId = component.get("v.contactId");
        let closeDate = component.get("v.selectedDate");
        let typeDelivery =component.get("v.selectedTypeDelivery");
        let deliveryAddress = component.get("v.deliveryAdress");
        let firstName = component.get("v.firstName");
        let lastName =component.get("v.lastName");
        let email = component.get("v.email");
        let priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap = component.get("v.priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap");
        let priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap1=new Map();
        priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap1.set('01u2w000001bwLJAAY',1);
        priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap1.set('01u2w000001bwLKAAY',1);
            action.setParams({ "leadId": '00Q2w0000019T7lEAE',"contactId" : 'EmptyContact',"closeDate" : closeDate,
            "typeDelivery" : 'Pickup' , "deliveryAddress" : '', 
            "priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap" : priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap1,
            "firstName" : '', "lastName" : '', "email" : 'wqweqws@adasd.com'});
            action.setCallback(this, function (response) {
            let state = response.getState();
            let err = response.getError();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                alert("SUCCESS");
            }
            else {
                console.log("Failed with state: " + state);
                alert('fail');
                console.log("OpportunityComponent(createOpportunity) alert(err[0].message): "+ err[0].message);
            }
        });
        $A.enqueueAction(action);
    },
```

### CreateOpportunityController.cls

```
@AuraEnabled
public static void createOpportunityMethod(String leadId,String contactId,Date closeDate,String typeDelivery,String deliveryAddress,Map<String,Integer> priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap,String firstName,String lastName,String email) {
    Map<Product2,String> productWithQuantity= new Map<Product2,String>();
    Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();
    List<PricebookEntry> pricebookEntrys= [SELECT Id,UnitPrice,Product2Id FROM PricebookEntry WHERE Id IN :priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap.keySet()];
    System.debug('pricebookEntrys: '+pricebookEntrys);
    List<String> productIds=new List<String>();
    for (PricebookEntry pricebookEntry : pricebookEntrys) {
        productIds.add(pricebookEntry.Product2Id);
    }
    System.debug('productIds: '+productIds);
    List<Product2> products = [SELECT Id,(SELECT UnitPrice,Id FROM PricebookEntries) FROM Product2 WHERE Id IN :productIds ];
    Map<Product2,Integer> productWithQuantityMap =new Map<Product2,Integer>();
    System.debug('products :'+products);
    System.debug('priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap :'+priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap);
    for (Product2 product : products) {
        for (String pricebookEntryIdKey : priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap.keySet()) {
            if(pricebookEntryIdKey==product.PricebookEntries[0].Id){                    
               productWithQuantityMap.put(product,priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap.get(pricebookEntryIdKey));
            } 
        }
    }
    System.debug('productWithQuantityMap :'+productWithQuantityMap);
    opp.CloseDate=closeDate;
    opp.Pricebook2Id ='01s2w000005VkPmAAK';
    if(leadId=='newLead'){
        Lead lead = new Lead(FirstName = firstName , LastName = lastName , Email = email , Company = 'none');
        insert lead;
        opp.LeadId__c=lead.Id;
        opp.Name = 'Opportunity'+lead.Id;
    }
    else{
        if(leadId != 'EmptyLead'){
            opp.LeadId__c=leadId;
            opp.Name = 'Opportunity'+leadId;

        }
        if(contactId!= 'EmptyContact'){
            opp.ContactId__c=contactId;
            opp.Name = 'Opportunity'+contactId;
        } 
    }
    opp.StageName='Opened';
    opp.DeliveryType__c=typeDelivery;
    if(typeDelivery=='Delivery'){
        opp.DeliveryAdress__c=deliveryAddress;
    }
    // opp.StoreId__c=store.Id; 
    insert opp;
    createAllOpportunityProduct(opp,productWithQuantityMap);
}

  @AuraEnabled
    public static void createAllOpportunityProduct(Opportunity opp,Map<Product2,Integer> productWithQuantityMap){
        List<OpportunityLineItem> opportunityProductsList =new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
        OpportunityLineItem opportunityProduct =new OpportunityLineItem();
        for (Product2 productKey : productWithQuantityMap.keySet()) {
            opportunityProduct.UnitPrice = productKey.PricebookEntries[0].UnitPrice;
            opportunityProduct.OpportunityId = opp.Id;
            opportunityProduct.Product2Id = productKey.Id;
            opportunityProduct.Quantity = productWithQuantityMap.get(productKey);
            opportunityProductsList.add(opportunityProduct);
            opportunityProduct = new OpportunityLineItem();
        }
        insert opportunityProductsList;     
    }
```

When I execute (

```
date myDate = date.newInstance(1987, 12, 17);
Map<String,Integer> priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap =new Map<String,Integer>();
priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap.put('01u2w000001bwLJAAY',1);
priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap.put('01u2w000001bwLKAAY',1);
CreateOpportunityController.createOpportunityMethod('00Q2w0000019T7lEAE','EmptyContact',myDate,'Pickup','',priceBookEntryIdWithQuantityMap,'','','wqweqws@adasd.com');
```

) from Anonymous Window then created Opportunity and 2 Opportunity Product,but when I execute from my Site same Method(`createOpportunityMethod`) with the same argument ,I get only  Opportunity  without  OpportunityProducts and I don't get any errors from Method(`createOpportunityMethod`).

I have set all permissions at the level of fields and objects(Opportunities,Opportunity Product,Price Book Entry,Price Books,Products) in the site profile

Comment: can you remove some of these logs? they really make it hard to read your code and determine what is going on here. While logs can be helpful, too much of them can just make it impossible to follow. Or at the least, add some space between the logs and the logic.

Comment: you're right I forgot to delete it